# PayPal subscription billing modification not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

We are using PayPal Payments Standard (aka Website Payments Standard) for our users subscription billing system.

Users want to upgrade their subscription from monthly to yearly for example.

So I generated a new subscription button with the new subscription parameters on my website, then click goto Paypal form, I see the current and new subscription on paypal platform, fine : (the amounts and cycle duration are simple tests values to demonstrate the problem)

[image]

Then click on SAVE button but paypal give an error saying :

```
"Amount can only be increased by 20%"
```

Paypal think I am only changing the price but it is not true I am also changing the billing duration (from month to year).

Do you know if it is possible with Paypal or the only way is to cancel the current subscription and start a new one ? That would be so bad from paypal.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the PayPal API documentation, that is built in to their systems https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/#id086530108PM